# Можно ли добавлять в класс поля, которые служат только для улучшения читаемости кода?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

У меня есть класс, в нем ест вот такое поле:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>> costs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Далее, во всех циклах(а их у меня много в этом классе)  использую следующие конструкции:

```
for (int i = 0; i < costs.get(row).size(); i++)
```

или вот так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < costs.size(); i++)
```

Будет лучше, если я добавлю 2 поля?

```
private int costsSize;
private int costsRowSize;
```

И дальше во всех циклах буду использовать их. Спрашиваю об этом потому что никакой дополнительной смысловой нагрузки они вроде бы не несут, везде можно обойтись без них. Но код они сделает покороче и яснее. Еще у меня в этом классе есть геттер, который как раз возвращает размер (потому что во внешнем коде этот размер тоже нужен).

```
public int getCritCount() {
    return costs.size();
}
```

Может быть стоит использовать его в качестве условия цикла? Но мне кажется что лучше всего были бы все-таки поля класса. Ведь подставить их в условие занимает меньше процессорного времени чем каждый раз вызывать там метод. Но никак не могу отделаться от мысли что они не несут смысловой нагрузки и никак не описывают состояние этого объекта.

Comment: Не будет. Читаемость они только ухудшат, потому что их происхождение ясно не будет. И вообще они к состоянию никакого отношения не имеют.

Comment: @Etki, к состоянию отношения не имеют, я же это написал. А почему читаемость не улучшат? Разве i < costsRowSize не лучше читается чем costs.get(0).size()? И быстродействие не ухудшается при втором варианте?

Comment: costRowSize значит costs.get(0).size, А для costs.get(1).size() или costs.get(123).size() какое поле? Что за дискриминация по номеру индекса отличного от нуля? Надо для всех i от 0 до Integer.MAX_VALUE (=2^31-1) понаделать полей для читаемости вида costRow_i_Size. Вот это увлекательное чтиво будет! А уж набор исходного текста класса...

Comment: @banme, это был бы конечно бред, я понимаю. Но дело в том что у меня каждый список из costs имеет одинаковый размер. Думал что это не относится к делу - но видимо надо немного рассказать. По логике моей задачи costs представляет собой матрицу. Элементы costs - это строки матрицы, и они имеют одинаковый размер. В общем вызовом costs.get(0).size() я получаю количество столбцов матрицы.

Comment: Матрица где-то там http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/

Comment: @banme, оу, спасибо! Получается что велосипед писал

Comment: Изобретать велосипеды полезно. Это не единственная математическая библиотека и для некоторых задач далеко не самая лучшая. Благодаря изобретателям имеется некоторое количество библиотек для матриц, среди которых можно даже выбрать подходящую для себя. Но нет предела совершенству

Answer (score 5):

Заводить поля — это странно, потому что вы по сути продублируете информацию, которая уже хранится в коллекции. Если размеры разойдутся, то вы получите либо выход за границу коллекции, либо неполный обход коллекции. От такого решения больше вреда, чем пользы.

Проблема с геттерами в том, что банальная логика полного обхода коллекции теперь начинает зависеть от вызова метода. Конструкция `for (int i = 0; i < costs.size(); i++) { ... costs[i] ... }` очевидна и распознаётся с первого взгляда. Конструкция `for (int i = 0; i < getCostsSize(); i++) { ... costs[i] ... }` — уже нет.

Лично я не заморачивался бы с геттерами, а либо использовал ваш код как есть, либо добавил локальные переменные. Какой-нибудь микрооптимизатор может понабежать и сказать, что вызывать `costs.get(row).size()` в цикле неэффективно.

Если бы вы использовали C#, я бы посоветовал использовать двумерный массив, если вы не меняете размер таблицы. Ну или можно воспользоваться классами для работы с матрицами, как посоветовали в комментариях.

Comment: В жаве, если что, тоже можно делать двумерные и более массивы фиксированной размерностью.

Comment: @banme Многомерные массивы в джаве реализованы "лесенкой", то есть как массивы, содержащие массивы, содержащие массивы. "Параллелепипедность" многомерного массива джава не гарантирует, с кэшем процессора пролёт. В шарпе, плюсах и прочих языках есть многомерные массивы, которые размещаются в едином блоке памяти (в дополнение к многомерным массивам "лесенкой").

Comment: long[][] вместо `ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>>` сойдёт.

Comment: @banme Сойдёт-то сойдёт, то преимуществ лестничного массива над листами листов не так много, как у полноценного двумерного массива. Шило на мыло.

Comment: Вряд ли у человека стоит сейчас вопрос о быстродействии серьёзных математических расчётов.

Comment: @banme, Всем спасибо за помощь! Листы выбрал потому что надо постоянно менять размер, более того нужна делать вставку элементов в определенную позицию. По-моему с массивом это не просто. А почему думаете что не интересует быстродействие? Потому что видна моя неопытность и недостаток знаний? Но это же не значит что не надо стремится писать правильно и быстро. Просто возможно интересует не в первую очередь.

Comment: Быстродействие нужно для сложных расчётов, с большими, огромными матрицами. На жава в таких задачах никто серьезно не рассчитывает, но используют в жаве нативные библиотеки из с, из фортрана. Разница в скорости на порядок в лучшем случае. 50 сек против 5сек ощутимо же? Тут как ни старайтесь, даже вон опытные ничего поделать не могут.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Самому сделать матрицу на самом деле не сложно. И даже постоянно меняющуюся. Что нужно в матрице? `get(i, j)` получить элемент `set(i, j, value)` установить элемент, `getN`/`setN`, `getM`/`setM` - получить/установить размерности. Все ваши ужасные условия и цепочки спрячутся внутри главным образом `set`. Клиента класса будет вызывать только `m.get(i, j)` и `m.set(i, j, v)`

Comment: @banme, Соглашусь насчет быстродействия в Java. Но если уж выбрал этот язык и не использую нативные функции, то все равно же надо следить? Одну и ту же задачу ведь и на чистой Java можно написать по разному в плане быстродействия. Насчет класса для матрицы - очень интересно, спасибо! Только вот вопрос, не будет ли это неправильно с точки зрения ООП? Все-таки к моей предметной области относится класс Task, а матрица не относится. Класс Task должен работать с матрицами - это его обязанность. Наверное стоит сделать класс Matrix  внутренним для Task? Или использовать инкапсуляцию на уровне пакета?